# unable to use session variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using a codeigniter and i have 3 controller, i use the session to store username from the 1st controller and i use this to determine from the other controller if someone is logged in.

Here is a the constructor of the first controller, in this class, i also use the statement where i give a value to `$_SESSION['username']` so the other controller use it:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
  session_start();
  parent::__construct();

}

public function index()
{

  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]');

  if ( $this->form_validation->run() !== false ) {
     // then validation passed. Get from db
     $this->load->model('Login_Model');
     $res = $this->Login_Model->verify_user(
                 $this->input->post('userName'), 
                 $this->input->post('password')
              );

     if ( $res !== false ) {
        $tempuser = $this->input->post('username');
        $_SESSION['username'] = $tempuser;
        redirect(base_url());
     }

  }

  $this->load->view('login_view');
}
```

This is the 2nd controller, on he constructor, i created a conditional statement to determine if someone is logged in, i tested this and it's still ok:

```
class Pagination extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent:: __construct();
    $this->load->helper("url");
        session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
           redirect(base_url().'index.php/login');
        }

}
```

In the 3rd controller, this is where i encounter the problem, i cannot access the variable where i stored the username, here is the code:

```
class Blood_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
      session_start();
    parent::__construct();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        redirect(base_url().'index.php/login');
    }
 }
```

It always go inside the if statement even if i enter a rightusername on the 1st controller.
can anyone help?

Comment: Where are you writing the `username` to the session?

Comment: on the first controller when some one logged in with a correct username and password.

Comment: you should paste that code aswell

Comment: I only see a `session_start`. No assignment at all.

Comment: Can you try to add `session_start()` to the top of main index.php file? And remove all another `session_start()` from the code.

Answer (score 1):

load this  "$this->load->library('session'); " in the constructor ie in here

```
public function __construct()
{
  session_start();
  parent::__construct();

 }
```

and remove the session_start() and use

```
 `$this->session->set_userdata('username', $tempuser);`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always good idea to check if session is already exists.

Try:

```
if (!session_id())
  session_start();
```

And try to var_dump($_SESSION); in 3rd controller after session_start() to check what is inside.

Answer (score 0):

Need to set session data using $_SESSION array in this case instead of CI session library ie. replace `$this->session->set_userdata('username', $tempuser);` with `$_SESSION['username'] = $tempuser`

Comment: Did you try to remove all `session_start()` from controllers and add this only once in the top of the main (CI root) index.php file?

Comment: i just tried it, and it didnt work, and 2nd controller cannot access it too.

Answer (score 0):

remove all the session_start(); and set it in the config -> autoload.php

change '`!==`'to  "`!=`' and check the session variable value

Comment: i dont have problem with that because the $_SESSION['username'] is still accessible inside the 2nd controller. the problem is, $_SESSION['username'] has no value when im using it on the 3rd controller

Comment: ok, you are saying that you have value for $_SESSION['username'] in the 1st controller, did you echo it outside the if statement int the 3rd controller

Comment: yes, but nothing their is nothing. when i try it on the 2nd controller. it has a value

Comment: remove all the session_start(); and set it in the config -> autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the Session class manually in your controller constructor, use the $this->load->library function:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Don't need to use session_start() in codeigniter.

Once loaded, the Sessions library object will be available using: $this->session

On the other hand if you don't want to initialize the Session class manually in your every controller constructor, then you can autoload it from your application/config/autoload.php file,just add session class name in $autoload['libraries'] array like this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation', 'session');
```

Now you can set your session data like this way:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_name', $user_name);
```

And you can retrieve your session data like this way:

```
$user_name = $this->session->userdata('user_name');
```

Go here to learn more about CI session : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html